# converting lines of imported text file to arrays and printing arrays to make graph in Netbeans and Swing

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I want to import any .txt files (note the .txt files will have a 3 sets of numbers in one column; separating each set with a space)

```
2   
3    
4   

3   
2   
1  

1   
2  
3
```

and convert the set of numbers into arrays. (array 1 , 2 and 3)

```
array1[] = {2,3,4}   
array2[] = {3,2,1}   
array3[] = {1,2,3}
```

then be able to graph the array in JFreeGraph Library
here's how i started...i'm using netbeans and java Swing

```
   @Action
public void openMenuItem() {

    int returnVal = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);     
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {  
        File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();

    try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);    
            jTextArea2.read(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), null);         

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

Comment: i want put the numbers from the .txt file into separate arrays.. how would i get along doing that

Answer (score 2):

Read from a file line by line, perhaps using [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). Once you encounter an empty line - you have a new set of numbers. Here is an oversimplified example that maintains a list of lists, and reads only strings:

```
public static List<List<String>> parseFile(String fileName){
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> currentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists.add(currentList);

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.isEmpty()){
                currentList = new ArrayList<String>();
                lists.add(currentList);
            } else {
                currentList.add(line);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedReader != null)
                bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return lists;
}
```

**EDIT**: using resulting lists with JTextArea

```
List<List<String>> lists = parseFile("test.txt");
for (List<String> strings : lists){
    textArea.append(StringUtils.join(strings, ",") + "\n");
    System.out.println(StringUtils.join(strings, ","));
}
```

Comment: awesome! now how would i call out the arrays that was made here for other usage? IE : to print out the arrays in a jTextArea?